# Can $A, B$ fail to commute if $e^A=e^B=e^{A+B}=id$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the real $n \times n$-matrices $A$ and $B$.

> Can $A, B$ fail to commute if $e^A=e^B=e^{A+B}=id$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $A$ and $B$ can fail to commute. Consider
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr@{}}
     0 & 1 & 0 \\
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right],\qquad
B = \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    0                  & -\tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
    \tfrac{1}{2}        & 0            & 0 \\
   -\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0            & 0
\end{array}\right],
$$
so that
$$
A + B = \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
     0                  & \tfrac{1}{2} & \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
    -\tfrac{1}{2}        & 0           & 0 \\
    -\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & 0           & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$
Since each of $A$, $B$, and $A + B$ has [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) equal to $\sqrt{2}$, we have
$$
\exp(2\pi A) = \exp(2\pi B) = \exp\bigl(2\pi (A + B)\bigr) = I.
$$
However, it's easy to check $AB$ is not symmetric, so
$$
BA = (-B^{T})(-A^{T}) = B^{T}A^{T} = (AB)^{T} \neq AB.
$$
It follows, of course, that $2\pi A$ and $2\pi B$ don't commute, either.

Comment: Nice example. It would be interesting to determine if there is any $2 \times 2$ example.

Comment: If a matrix $M$ has Frobenius norm equal to $\sqrt{2}$, then $\exp(2 \pi M)=I$ ?
Ok nice. But can you give me some keywords to find further readings to this, please?

Comment: @HansEngler: There are no smaller examples because the space of skew-symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices is one-dimensional (so the bracket is trivial). :)

Comment: @Siggi: I neglected to emphasize that the matrices in question are _skew-symmetric_. The example rests on the fact that if $A$ is a real, skew-symmetric matrix of Frobenius norm $\sqrt{2}$, then $\exp(2\pi A) = I$. For further reading, you might start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_rotation#Infinitesimal_rotations).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Siggi: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**This is wrong.** If $e^{A+B}=I$, then $A+B=2n\pi i$, for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, i.e., $2n\pi i-A=B$. Consider $[A,B]=AB-BA=A(2n\pi i-A)-(2n\pi i-A)A=-AA+AA=0$. Hence, if $e^{A+B}=I$, then $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: $e^C=I$, DOES NOT IMPLY that $C=0$! For example $C=2\pi i I$.

Comment: That's not right, e.g. $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2\pi \\ 2\pi & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ has $e^A = I$.

Comment: Still wrong after the edit. Note that $A + B = 2 n \pi i$ makes no sense since $A, B$ are matrices.